# Issue to update database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

SQL Server is running over TCP/IP.

When I try to first update-database

```
PM> update-database
```

> Build started... Build succeeded. ...........
> ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error
> Number:-1,State:0,Class:20 A network-related or instance-specific
> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
> server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
> name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
> connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating
> Server/Instance Specified)

Firewall is correct, rules are added for ports 1433, 1434, 55120.

I have a connection in Visual Studio to SQL Server The connection string in appsettings.json is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ProductionManagmentContext": "Server=DESKTOP-MAQO344\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ProductionManagment.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Comment: SQL Express requires that you enable remote connections if you are attempting to connect remotely.  Have you done that?

Comment: see if the sql browser is running, and also if the protokoll tcp/ip is enabled

Comment: If you add -Verbose to package manager does that give you any more info?

Comment: Instance name resolution requires that the SQL Browser service is running and accessible via udp/1434 (as opposed to tcp/1434). If you've just installed a new instance, or reconfigured the protocols for one, you need to restart the SQL Browser service for it to detect the new configuration.